# SBT apply Task after Compile

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt, task

I am able to automatically execute a task before compilation with:

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(myTask)
```

How do I do the same but *after* compile?

I know I can do:

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile) map{x=>
  // post-compile work
  doFoo()
  x
}
```

to execute arbitrary Scala code, but I need to automatically execute the target task itself when a compile event occurs

Doing something like:

```
val foo = TaskKey[Unit]("foo", "...")
val fooTask = foo <<= scalaInstance map {si =>
...
} dependsOn(compile in Compile)
```

works if I type "foo" from sbt> prompt; i.e. task is executed after compile, but the goal is to hook into compile task itself, so anytime a compilation occurs, the foo task is automatically called after compilation completes.

Is this possible, or am I going about things in the wrong way to hook into the built-in compile task?

Comment: Can you explain the use case?

Comment: @MarkHarrah, Play has a limitation where javascript reverse routing for sub projects can only be generated at runtime. I need the routes generated as a static file at compile time, which I have accomplished, with exception of hooking in the task as a post-compile operation (i.e. I need to first compile the application, otherwise new routes won't be accounted for in routes generation task).

Comment: Are these files that are being generated considered resources?

Comment: @MarkHarrah, certainly not source files, the content is static. So sure, they're resources, but nothing SBT/Play needs to know about after they're written (using 3rd party static assets manager). I'm writing routes files to a directory within the parent/aggregator project if that helps.

Comment: Ok.  What I'm getting at is that something uses the content.  The thing that uses these files should depend on `myTask` somehow.  For example, if they were resources that needed to be packaged, you'd add `myTask` as a resource generator.  If they should be on a classpath, `myTask` should be added to it.

Comment: That's just it, what depends on routes task (Grunt JS, which copies from project directory to local front end apache www directory) has nothing to do with SBT/Play; basically I have multi-project Play application with zero assets, so there are no resources to manage. It's not a huge deal, I should be able to use dependsOn for the task in dist, and then remember (spaceshot) to run the task during development, when I'm actually add/edit/delete/ing routes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, there is some task that depends on your task.

If `compile` is being used to mean "compile and set things up for Grunt", then create a `prepareGrunt` task that depends on `compile` and `myTask` and run that instead.

If `myTask` should run before the project's classes and resources are used by something else, then make it a dependency of `exportedProducts`.  Tasks like `run` and `test` and tasks in dependent projects will get the exported classpath entries from that task.

The danger in "run sometime after compile" is that `myTask` won't be run before the task that actually needs it.  There is the `triggeredBy` method on `Initialize[Task[T]]`, but it is easily abused and should only be used when the output of the task is known to be used only after all tasks execute.

Comment: +1 thanks Mark, you're doing incredible work with SBT, keep it up (don't forget to sleep though ;-))