# sbt to run a custom task whenever runtime code is compiled

Tags: sbt

**How can I make sbt run a custom task whenever the code of `Runtime` configuration is compiled?**

Given this task:

```
val myCustomTask = taskKey[Unit]("Prints a greeting")

myCustomTask := {
  println("Hello from myCustomTask!")
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
compile := {(compile in Compile) dependsOn myCustomTask}.value
```

That does what I want when `sbt compile` is run.

However, my custom task is *not* run when I run `sbt test`, even though `sbt test` makes sbt also compile the runtime sources if needed, not only test sources:

```
sbt clean test
...
[info] Compiling 19 Scala sources to /myproject/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources to /myproject/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
..
```

I read that `test:compile` implies a `compile`, but how? It doesn't seem to depend on `compile` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `triggeredBy` does what I wanted ([SBT run code in project after compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434535/sbt-run-code-in-project-after-compile)).

With that I get:

```
sbt clean test
...
[info] Compiling 19 Scala sources to /myproject/target/scala-2.11/classes...
Hello from myCustomTask!
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources to /myproject/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
..
```